# Is this proper javascript for making a namespace that encapsulates various methods into different objects?

Tags: javascript, namespaces, object, encapsulation

```
var namespaced = {
    A: function(){
        function r(){
            //do some stuff
            return something;
        }

        var someProperty = 5;     

        function j(){
            //do some more stuff
            return something;
        }     
    },

    B: function(){   
        //can I call A and C?
        A.r();
        C.d();
    },

    C: function(){
        function d() {
            //do stuff we like
        }    
    }
}
```

Then I could do...

```
namespaced.A.j();

namespaced.C.d();

something = namespaced.A.someProperty;
```

right?

Would I need to do this too?

```
var something = new namespaced.A()?
```

If so does A() have a constructor? I'm really confused here :{

I'm trying to encapsulate my javascript so it's easy to maintain

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> Then I could do...
>
> ```
> namespaced.A.j();
> namespaced.C.d();
> something = namespaced.A.someProperty;
> ```

No you couldn't. The function `j` and `someProperty` are only local to `A` and are not propagated to the outside. If you want to access them from the outside, you have to make them a property of the function, using `this`:

```
var namespaced = {
    A: function(){
        this.r = function(){
            //do some stuff
            return something;
        };

        this.someProperty = 5;     

        this.j = function(){
            //do some more stuff
            return something;
        };
    }
}
```

But you would still need to call `var a = new namespaced.A()` in order to access the functions.

If you want to call `namespaced.A.j()` directly, you would have to declare `A` as object, not as function:

```
var namespaced = {
    A: {
        r: function(){
            //do some stuff
            return something;
        },

        someProperty: 5,     

        j: function(){
            //do some more stuff
            return something;
        }     
    }
}
```

So it depends on what you want to achieve eventually... to get a better insight into these methods, I recommend [*JavaScript Patterns*](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0596806752).

Answer (score 2):

This is what you need to understand about JavaScript:

- When you write

```
    var obj = { A: a, B: b, C: c };
```

you are creating (and assigning to `obj`) an object with properties called `A`, `B` and `C` mapping to values `a`, `b` and `c` respectively. These values may very well be functions, so when you have

```
    var obj = { A: function(){...} };
```

you are creating an object with a property called "A" which is a function. You can refer to it with `obj.A` and call with `obj.A()`.

- When you call `obj.A()`, the keyword `this` inside the body of function `A` will refer to `obj`. You can use it to assign new properties to `obj`:

```
    var obj = {  
        A: function() { this.prop = "Hello!"; }
    };  
    obj.A();  
    alert( obj.prop ); // alerts "Hello!"
```

So, inside `namespaced.A.j()` the `this` keyword will point to `namespace.A` (it's what is to the left of the last dot).

- You can apply a function to an object like so: `func.apply(obj)` or like so: `func.call(obj)`. In this case, the `this` keyword will refer to `obj` instead. This isn't relevant to your case, but if `func` takes parameters (let's say `param1` and `param2`), you can apply the function like so: `func.apply(obj, [val1, val2])` or like so: `func.call(obj, val1, val2)`.
- All variables declared inside a function live only inside that function. They are not visible outside. And when you write `function doStuff(){}` it's (I'm simplifying here) as good as if you wrote `var doStuff = function(){};` So nested functions live and can be used only inside the surrounding function; that is, unless you assign them to something accessible from outside.
- When you call something like `new Cons()` what happens is the creation of a new empty object followed by the application of `Cons()` on that object. In other words, it's the same as

  ```
      var obj = {};
  Cons.apply(obj);
  ```

  or if you prefer:

```
    var obj = {};
    obj.Cons = Cons;
    obj.Cons();
    // obj's Cons property then mysteriously disappears
    // unless it was explicitly set inside Cons() (oh my, how confusing! :)
```

So you can have this:

```
    function Duck(name){
        this.myName = name;
        this.quack = function(){
            alert(this.myName + " quacks!");
        }
    };
    donald = new Duck('Donald');
    donald.quack();
```

---

With all the preceding in mind, a way to write namespaced code is like this:

```
// The following syntax, confusing to someone who hasn't seen it before,
// is defining a new anonymous function and immediately using it
// as a constructor applied to a new empty object.
//
// Alternatively, you can use this syntax:
//   var namespaced = {};
//   (function(){
//       ....
//   }).apply(namespaced);
//
var namespaced = new (function(){

    // This creates a new variable named "namespaced"
    // which is visible only inside this anonymous function.
    // This variable points to the still-empty object created by
    // 'new'. This object will, once we're done with this anonymous function,
    // be assigned to a variable, outside, which by "coincidence" is
    // also named "namespaced".
    var namespaced = this;

    // You could alternatively not create the variable "namespaced"
    // and use 'this' directly inside this anonymous function. But,
    // the 'this' keyword may point to different objects inside the
    // nested functions that follow, so we create it to avoid confusion.


    // This assigns a new object to variable 'A', which isn't visible outside.
    // Use a constructor function defined inline.
    var A = new (function(){
        var A = this;  // 'this' now refers to the empty object created just above

        this.someProperty = 5;  // Two different ways of
        A.anotherProperty = 7;  // doing mostly the same thing

        this.j = function(){
            //do some more stuff
            // 'this' will point to j, here
            return something;
        }

        // Function r isn't visible outside of A's constructor like this!
        function r(){
            //do some stuff
            return something;
        }

        // Make 'r' visible outside by assigning it to a property of 'A'.
        // Look, it's also called "r". What fun!
        A.r = r;
    })();

    // Make the object in variable 'A' visible outside of
    // 'namespaced's constructor, by making it a property of 'namespaced'
    namespaced.A = A;


    // Create a new object as before.
    // This time we won't make it visible outside
    // of "namespaced"'s constructor.
    var C = new (function(){
        this.d = function (){
            //do stuff we like
        }    
    })();


    // Give "namespaced" a property 'B'.
    // This time it's a function instead of a nested object.
    namespaced.B = function(){
        // It's cool to make these function calls here, because
        // (a) nested functions can see the variables ('A' & 'C')
        // of surrounding functions, even if they terminate in the meantime;
        // and (b) 'r' & 'd' are properties of 'A' and 'C'.
        A.r();
        C.d();
    };


    // You could return 'this' or 'namespaced' from this constructor,
    // but the 'new' keyword will make sure the "namespaced" variable
    // outside will get the no-longer-empty object it created,
    // so you can just not return anything.
})();





// Now you can do
five = namespaced.A.someProperty;
seven = namespaced.A.anotherProperty;

something = namespaced.A.j();

namespaced.B(); // Calls A.r() and C.d()

// But you can't do
namespaced.C.d(); // WRONG: "namespaced" doesn't have a property named "C"
```

I hope this helps more than it confuses.